# Solving a series $n(1 + n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 +.......n^{n-1})$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to sum the following series?

> $n(1 + n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 +.......n^{n-1})$

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Any equation? ${}$

Comment: actually, just the series summation.

Comment: This more recent post (applied to $r=a=n$) answers your question: [Deriving Sum of a Geometric Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060166/deriving-sum-of-a-geometric-progression)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is called a geometric series.

$$n(1+n+n^2+\cdots n^{n-1})=n\frac{n^n-1}{n-1}$$

Why?

$$S=1+n+n^2+\cdots n^{n-1}$$

$$nS=n+n^2+n^3+\cdots n^{n}$$

$$S(1-n)=1-n^{n}$$

$$S=\frac{1-n^{n}}{1-n}$$

Comment: This is the case $n \ne 1$, of course.  We can also do that case, but by other methods.

Answer (score 4):

Let $ n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + n^n = Sum $

Then,

$ 1 + n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + n^n  = Sum + 1$

$ n \times (1 + n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + n^n ) = n \times (Sum + 1)$

$ n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + n^n + n^{n+1} = n\times Sum + n$

$ (n + n^2 + n^3 + n^4 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + n^n) + n^{n+1} = n\times Sum + n$

$ (Sum)+ n^{n+1} = n\times Sum + n$

$ n^{n+1} = (n-1) \times Sum + n$

$ n^{n+1} -n = (n-1) \times Sum$

$ \frac {n^{n+1} -n}{n-1} = Sum$

Hence,

$ Sum = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} n^i = \frac {n^{n+1} -n}{n-1} $

Comment: nice. thank you