# Deriving Sum of a Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to derive the sum of a geometric progression: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{ar^i}$$
This is equal to:
$$ar^0+ar^1+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}$$
Factorising with $a$, I get:
$$a \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{r^i}$$

Assuming $r$ is $6$ for example, I get:
$$a\left[r^0(1+r(1+r(1+r(1+r(1+r)))))\right]$$
The number of $(1+r)$s inside is equal to $n-1$.

I have no idea how to expand the above equation, and simplify it.

Can someone please give me a step-by-step expansion and simplification of the equation. Something a $9^{th}$ grader would understand.

***EDIT***
In general, I don't understand how to expand nested braces(recursion isn't the most intuitive thing for me) so a ***very simple*** explanation of how this is done will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Call

$$
S = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}ar^i = a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n-1} \tag{1}
$$

if you multiply both sides by $r$ you get

$$
r S = ar + a r^2 + ar^3 + \cdots + ar^n \tag{2}
$$

When you subtract Eq. (1) from Eq. (2) you will see that most terms cancel out

\begin{eqnarray}
S - rS &=& S(1- r) = (a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{n-1}) - (ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots + ar^n) \\
&=& a - ar^n = a(1 - r^n)
\end{eqnarray}

So that

$$
S = a \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r} \tag{3}
$$

Therefore

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ar^i = a \frac{1-r^n}{1 - r} ~~~~~\mbox{if}~~~r\ne 1
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) However, I would ***really*** appreciate it if you 'completed' my derivation. I purposedully did **not** Google the answer.

Comment: @TobiAlafin Probably I misunderstood you, my apologies. But if you expand $a(1 + r(1 + r(1 + \cdots ))$ you are going to get back $a + ar+ ar^2 + \cdots$

Comment: P.S you have a small typo at the end of your answer. Too small for edit.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [difference of powers identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers):

$$
a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2 + \cdots + a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1})
$$

with $\,a=1, b=r\,$ gives $\;1-r^n=(1-r)(1+r+\cdots+ r^{n-1})\;$ therefore:

$$
1+r+\cdots+r^{n-1} = \cfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}
$$

Comment: Such a succint proof.

Comment: In the end, the difference of powers identity and the sum of a geometric progression formula are equivalent, modulo some simple algebraic manipulation. Guess it comes down to which one you learned first, and are more at ease with.

Answer (score 3):

**Without words**:

$$\begin{align}S=&a+ar^1+ar^2+...\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ar^{n-1}\\
rS=&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ar^1+ar^2+ar^3+...\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ar^{n}\end{align}$$

$$rS-S=ar^n-a$$
$$S=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The following recurrence should be obvious:

$$S_{n+1}=rS_n+a,$$ with $S_0=0$.

We can solve it by the theory of linear recurrences. The solution is made of an homogeneous part, such that

$$H_{n+1}=rH_n,$$ i.e. $$H_n=Cr^n$$

and a particular non-homogenous part,

$$N_{n+1}=rN_n+a$$ that is fulfilled by a constant,

$$N=rN+a,$$ or

$$N=\frac a{1-r}.$$

The other constant is obtained from the initial condition and

$$S_0=H_0+N_0=C+N=0.$$

Putting all pieces together,

$$S_n=\frac a{1-r}-\frac{a}{1-r}r^n.$$

---

In the special case that $r=1$, the recurrence is

$$S_{n+1}=S_n+a$$ and the solution obviously $$S_n=an.$$