# Simplification of sum of exponentials?

Tags: exponentiation, simple-functions

Is there a way to simplify the expression $\sum _{k=0}^n 2^k$? That is, is there a way to write it without a $\sum$ or $\prod$ operator?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you notice any patterns when you plug in various values of $n$?

Comment: $2^{n+1}-1$. Sorry I’m just tired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving Sum of a Geometric Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060166/deriving-sum-of-a-geometric-progression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1 + 2 + 4 + \cdots 2^n = 11 \cdots 1_\text{binary}=2^{n+1}-1$$

In general, $\sum_{k=0}^n  a^n$ is a geometric series.