# Is my algebra book correct?

Tags: arithmetic

Pré álgebra for dummies Brasil edition

Fast multiplication with exponents

took a job that pays you 1 cent the first day, 2 cents
Here's an age-old question that still raises eyebrows: Imagine that you
you on the second day, 4 cents on the third day, and so on, doubling the
value every day, like this:

1 2 4 16 32 64 128 256 512

As you can see, in the first ten days of work, you would earn a
Over \$10 (actually \$10.23 )

Is this correct 100 cents =1 dollar———>512 cents=5.12 dollars

The statement says is 10 dollars..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving Sum of a Geometric Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060166/deriving-sum-of-a-geometric-progression)

Comment: Can’t understand this sorry

Comment: On the tenth day, you earn 5.12 dollars. In the first ten days, you would earn $.01+.02+\ldots+5.12=10.23$.

Comment: (-1) Less than 40 seconds of effort before claiming you can't understand... The duplicate should allow you to realize that $\sum_{k=1}^{10}2^{k-1}=2^{10}-1=1023.$

Comment: You have to add all the money you made during the first nine days. You are getting  $5.12 because you are only considering the last day.

Comment: If you find the answer below satisfactory, then please close your inquiry by clicking the green check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add all cents accumulated on all days